# Change background color of git conflict marker sections

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, color

If `git` is performing a 3-way merge and has a conflict it can't resolve, it marks up that area of the file like this:

```
No unresolvable conflicts here
<<<<<<< HEAD
xyz
||||||| parent of ...
abc
=======
123
>>>>>>> ...
```

Is there a way (and, if so, how) to change the background color of these 3 "sections":

- `<<<<<<< HEAD` through the line before `||||||| parent of ...`
- `||||||| parent of ...` through the line before `=======`
- The line after `=======` through the line `>>>>>>> ...`

(EDIT: The question revolves around if there's a way to highlight certain lines depending on other lines.  `xyz` would ordinarily not be highlighted, but since it's between `<<<<<<<` and `|||||||` it would be highlighted.)

With also being able to handle other sets of conflict markers?

Using the most recent version of vim available at the time of a comment.  So, as of now, 8.1.1183.

I use a black background and 256 colors in my terminal.  I was thinking it would be nice to give these sections using the darkest R/G/B/C/M/Y colors, so they didn't cause much of a problem with syntax highlighting.  (Talking about ANSI colors 52, 22, 17, 23, 53, and 58 - not the 1-6 colors.)

Comment: A simple google search query would have sufficed: https://github.com/rhysd/conflict-marker.vim

Comment: @klaus, I should have mentioned I looked at that plugin while doing a lot of google searching.  That plugin highlights the conflict markers themselves.  It doesn't also highlight the text those markers are associated with, on other lines.  I think the big issue at hand is if there's a way to highlight certain lines depending on other lines.  Meaning, in my example, `xyz` would ordinarily not be highlighted, but since it's between `<<<<<<<` and `|||||||` I would like it highlighted.

Comment: @user1902689 I just added the plugin after finally getting fed up with not having colors for conflicts, and yeah it just takes a little bit of plugin experience to know the gotchas with this. You have to follow the documentation in this section: https://github.com/rhysd/conflict-marker.vim#highlight-conflict-markers and you have to paste the code after the plugin loads. I'm using vim-plug and need to put it after the `call plug#end()`. In that readme you can see the screenshot the author has posted. It works as you want, and you can customize the highlight colors of everything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Vim config, you can do the following (change the colors and styling to your liking):

```
function! ConflictsHighlight() abort
    syn region conflictStart start=/^<<<<<<< .*$/ end=/^\ze\(=======$\||||||||\)/
    syn region conflictMiddle start=/^||||||| .*$/ end=/^\ze=======$/
    syn region conflictEnd start=/^\(=======$\||||||| |\)/ end=/^>>>>>>> .*$/

    highlight conflictStart ctermbg=red ctermfg=black
    highlight conflictMiddle ctermbg=blue ctermfg=black
    highlight conflictEnd ctermbg=green cterm=bold ctermfg=black
endfunction

augroup MyColors
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter * call ConflictsHighlight()
augroup END
```

Which renders as follow:

[image]

Is it what you are after?

Comment: That's absolutely what I'm after.  I'm having some oddities with the vimscript though.  If I type your example in, it looks just like the image you posted.  If I save your example then restart vim editing the new file, it gets horribly out of whack.  (vim 8.1.1186.)  Even weirder, if I then delete all lines in an existing file showing weirdly, and re-paste its content, it's still showing wrong.  https://i.ibb.co/jvGMH6t/wtfvim.jpg

Comment: Using it in an actual merge scenario triggers an even weirder coloring than the image I linked, with: `conflictStart` being properly highlighted; the `|||||||` part of `conflictMiddle` in red but the rest of the line in blue as it should be; the `=======` in red; the `>>>>>>> .*` line in yellow (where did yellow come into this, there is no yellow); and the rest of the file which shouldn't be part of the conflict at all in green, still being picked up as `conflictEnd` according to the `SynStack()` function from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247603

Comment: Likewise, using the actual merge scenario, if I copy/paste the contents to a new file, it is displayed as expected, but as soon as it's saved and vim is restarted, it displays wrong.

Comment: In an actual merge scenario, you can disable the original diff coloration using `:diffoff`, leaving only the filetype's syntax highlight. I will play a bit to see for your first case.

Comment: Ack, sorry, had forgotten I had left the conflict_marker plugin installed after trying it before my post, which was conflicting and causing the problem.  Removing that and no longer having that problem.

Comment: I tried to edit a new file adding some conflicts, it behaved normally, then I saved the file, closed it and reopened it, and it was displayed as expected. Do you still encounter any of the previously mentioned issues since you removed the `conflict_marker` plugin?

Comment: No, all behaves well with that plugin removed.

Answer (score 1):

- [conflict-marker.vim](https://github.com/rhysd/conflict-marker.vim) can
  highlight the markers themselves; it also offers jumps and ways to resolve
  them.
- my own [ConflictDetection plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4129) detects and highlights the entire sections (via syntax highlighting); a companion [ConflictMotions plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3991) offers motions and commands for resolution.